# Merge join not able to join properly on varchar column

Tags: t-sql

I've created below code to implement SCD type 2 using merge, when i run the code i'm getting primary key violations on csname field. I have the below values as part of primary key, not sure whether merge SQL does support for varchar or not.
if I run the normal inner join SQL on the same key then i'm getting the matching records as well.

Any help much appreciated

csname
ER - Building Complaints
TR - Building Applications

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.load_target
AS

BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [TR_DW].[enum].[Rt]([csname],[enddatetime],[EffectiveToDate],[EffectiveFromDate],[CurrentRecord])
    SELECT[csname],[enddatetime],[EffectiveToDate],[EffectiveFromDate],[CurrentRecord]
    FROM
    (

    MERGE [TR_DW].[enum].[Rt] RtCSQSuTT
    USING [TR].[enum].[Rt] RtCSQSuST
    ON (RtCSQSuTT.csname = RtCSQSuST.csname)

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([csname],[enddatetime],[EffectiveToDate],[EffectiveFromDate],[CurrentRecord])
    VALUES ([csname],[enddatetime],'12/31/9999', getdate(), 'Y')
    WHEN MATCHED AND RtCSQSuTT.[CurrentRecord] = 'Y' AND 
    (ISNULL(RtCSQSuTT.[enddatetime], '') != ISNULL(RtCSQSuST.[enddatetime], ''))THEN
     UPDATE SET 
     RtCSQSuTT.[CurrentRecord] = 'N', 
     RtCSQSuTT.[EffectiveFromDate] = GETDATE() - 1,
     RtCSQSuTT.[EffectiveToDate] = GETDATE() 
     OUTPUT $Action Action_Taken,RtCSQSuST.[csqname],RtCSQSuST.[enddatetime],'12/31/9999' AS[EffectiveToDate],GETDATE() AS[EffectiveFromDate],'Y' AS[CurrentRecord]
)AS MERGE_OUT21
WHERE MERGE_OUT21.Action_Taken = 'UPDATE';

END 
GO
```

Comment: It looks to my like you're inserting twice. First within the merge you insert when not matching. Then any result (inserted or updated) is pushed through from the `OUTPUT` clause and is inserted again for the outside insert. Can you clarify - did you write this code? If so what was the purpose of this? Personally I usually prefer to use seperate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements as it is easier to performance tune and debug

Comment: basically i need to maintain the history (SCD type 2), so first inset for if the record is not exists and if exits expire the existing record and insert the new record from the source

Comment: First make sure there are no duplicate `csname` in `[tr].[enum].[rt]`. Also I would be wary of this: `ISNULL(RtCSQSuTT.[enddatetime], '')`. You're casting dates to strings there - bad idea.

Comment: Thank you Nick,                                                                                                what's the best way to compare the dates ?

Comment: Convert it to a legitimate date like 1900-01-01, not a string.